# How to remove dot from dictionary key in python

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, pymongo

I have python dictionary as follows:

```
 data=df.to_dict('records')
 print(data)
```

Gives Output:

```
    [{'id':'1','quantity.':2,'price':'350'},{'id':'2','quantity.':1,'price':'125'}, 
    {'id':'3','quantity.':4,'price':'500'}]
```

But while inserting in mongoDB using command `collection.insert_many(data)` it gives error as follows:

```
bson.errors.InvalidDocument: key 'quantity.' must not contain '.'
```

As we cannot store data with special characters in MongoDB, So how can I remove this dot '.' from all keys, So that i can insert data in MongoDB

Answer (score 2):

This comprehension ought to do it.

```
data = [{k.replace('.', ''): v for k, v in d.items()} for d in data]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using pandas, try:

```
data=data.rename({'quantity.':'quantity'}, axis='columns')
print(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of you using pandas, you can rename the specific column:

```
data = data.rename({'quantity.':'quantity'})
```

Or you can reassign the whole columns name with new one:

```
data.columns = ['id', 'quantity', 'price']
```